# Divide and conquer method to compute roots

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, performance

Knowing that we can use Divide-and-Conquer algorithm to compute large exponents, for example `2 exp 100 = 2 exp(50) * 2 exp(50)`, which is quite more efficient, is this method efficient using roots? For example `2 exp (1/100) = (2 exp(1/50)) exp(1/50)`?

In other words, I'm wondering if `(n exp(1/x))` is more efficient to `(n exp(1/y))` for `x < y` and where x and y are integers.

Comment: Probably not. You are dealing with floats and not integers here ...

Comment: Well this is what I'm wondering : Is (n exp(1/x)) more efficient to (n exp(1/y)) for x < y and where x and y are integers.

Comment: @hellsoul153 You could ask this on http://mathoverflow.net

Comment: According to their FAQ, MathOverflow is for research-level questions, which this is not.

Comment: With "n exp(x)", do you mean "n<sup>x</sup>"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `x,y` are floating point numbers `exp(1/x)` might not be more efficient than `exp(1/y)` for all `x<y`.

But point of divide and conquer algorithms is that

if we have something like `exp(1/x)` we won't calculate it again i.e. we divide `2^N` into two same problems of smaller size `2^(N/2) * 2^(N/2)` and we calculate `2^(N/2)` **only once**.

Similarly for `exp(2/x)` can be divided into `exp(1/x)*exp(1/x)` and we will have to calculate `exp(1/x)` only once. This should improve performance.

Also having **smaller number** in denominator should help.

*So I think this should work fine.*

Comment: I am not sure. The best way to get the answer is to use proper library. I just think that many issues are unnoticed and swept under the rug here. Applied math is an exciting discipline, but it can also be hard. I think we are over-simplifying the answer here. Also, I would use a library for computing an exponent rather than ding it myself.

Comment: Alright that aswers my question then, and sorry for the math error in my exemple :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a divide and conquer method is used when you have non-integer exponentials. I would assume that a taylor polynomial is used to compute x^y as e^(y ln(x)). You can compute the integer part of y, using divide and conquer then multiply it by the real part. But it doesn't make sense to divide it in two otherwise. Also:

2 exp (1/100) = (2 exp(1/50)) exp(1/50)

This is not true.

(2 exp(1/50))exp(1/50) = 2 exp(1/50+1/50)= 2*exp(1/25) != 2 exp(1/100)

You would be doing:

2 exp(1/100)= 2*exp(1/200)* exp(1/200)

Comment: He seems to mean something else (nonstandard) with "exp".

Comment: Okay, even if he means it as the exponential operator, he's still wrong when he writes 2^(1/100) =2^(1/50)2^(1/50). It would still have to be 2^(1/100)=2^(1/200) 2^(1/200). I actually can't think of an operation that would factor in the manner that he is.